# iOS8 disable auto-connect wifi

Tags: iphone, ipad, wifi, ios

iOS6 used to have the option to disable automatic connection to specific Wifi networks. This is gone in later versions of iOS yet is *crucial* in urban areas with abundant open *web login* networks in cafés etc. Has anyone figured out a hack, a third party app or so, to bring back this crucial feature?

**(Somebody else has censored this post, removing crucial details needed to avoid flak resulting from misunderstanding / not knowing the 3G signal/wifi issues where I live; see history for them. *Manually forgetting* a network after each use, or constantly turning wifi on/off, are *not* solutions!!)**

Comment: Perhaps you should just turn the wi-fi off when you don't want to use it.

Comment: The OP wants to use WiFi just top be able to choose which network

Comment: Someone please tell me how to stop this. I'm about to burn my iPhone!!